# Docker - Jenkins Image

Tags: jenkins, docker, dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline

I am building jenkins slave using docker image.

Need to install git on to the docker image. How can i do that.

Is there any docker image for git that can be used.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$ docker search jenkins | grep git
stephenreed/jenkins-java8-maven-git   Automated build that provides a continuous...   52                   [OK]
```

Comment: You recommend gitlab-ce? He wants git, not gitlab.

Answer (score 0):

If there is none, you can quickly build one with a small base image ([like Alpine](https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine/)), and a directive like:

```
# Install Git
RUN apt-get install git-core --assume-yes
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a simple docker image that comes packaged with Jenkins, Java8, Git, Maven and NodeJS. This covers most use cases so you don't have to keep making new Jenkins images every week.

[Jenkins + Docker Image](https://blog.qmo.io/how-to-make-jenkins-build-nodejs-ruby-and-maven-on-docker/)

And the relevant github for [source code](https://github.com/QuantumMob/jenkins)